Rsync to exfat external drive, quiet switch not working
I am attempting to use rsync to copy from my linux hard drive to an exfat external drive.
The working code to copy from ext4 to ext4 begins as: rsync -Razh
The code that I am attempting to use to copy from ext4 to exfat begins as rsync -hvrltD
The resulting output is too verbose. I want to suppress all output but errors.
I have tried the 'q' switch, but no matter what position I put that character in the option string, I get error messages.
What else do I need to do to suppress that output?
Thank you

From information you provided:

The code that I am attempting to use to copy from ext4 to exfat begins
as rsync -hvrltD

It's seen, that you have put switch "v":
Options
 -v, --verbose               increase verbosity

Try to remove that first.
